# Saving Umlaut in german language to database

Tags: php, laravel

I desperately try to save user input sent via POST request to my database, but the "Umlaute" like "ä, ü..." are not recognized. How can I fix this? I use UTF-8 already.

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

**Processing the user info**

```
$userData["firstName"] = e($bodyContent["firstName"]);
$userData["lastName"] = e($bodyContent["lastName"]);



 MFUser::create(array(
        'first_name' => $userData["firstName"],
        'last_name' => $userData["lastName"]
    ));
```

**Migration**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mfusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_reference')->unique();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->integer('user_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_types');
            $table->binary('salt', 16);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

But the output in the database for "Möller" is: M& uuml;ller"

Comment: You need to make sure the column and the database are UTF8. Also make sure the script is UTF8.

Comment: Maybe you could also var_dump $bodyContent["firstName"] and $userData["firstName"] to check if values are OK before inserting. Maybe the issue is not in database

Comment: wow... yeah.. you are right! When I dump $bodyContent it is "Möller", when I dump $userData it is M& uuml;ller". but this is coming from the e function I guess?

Comment: OK. Next step, what is `e` function, what does it do? The error is there

Comment: This gives the same result like htmlentities. I want to avoid SQL-Injection. I could use html_entity_decode before I save. But isn't it the sense of using htmlentities so this is not possible? When I convert back to UTF8 before I save, then the injection could work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e()` function is just a Laravel helper function for `htmlentities()`. However, `htmlentites()` should not be used to try to prevent SQL injection. It does not escape everything it needs to, and that is not its purpose; it is used when outputting your HTML to guard against XSS attacks. You don't want to run `htmlentites()` on your data before putting it into your database, you want to run it on your data after you've pulled it out and are about to show it (which is what blades double mustaches (`{{ }}`) already does).

Laravel's Eloquent uses PDO and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. That is already baked in for you, so there isn't anything you need to worry about unless you're using the `raw` functions for anything.

Remove the call to `e()` and you should be good to go.